# cannot find controls in gridview and get an error(Index was out of range)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Actually I have problem with finding LinkButton Control in gridview .
I have 2 gridviews which one of them is inside another one so my problem is I cannot get the value of LinkButton of second gridview,

here is my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
BorderStyle="None" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" GridLines="None">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
                    <table align="center" class="Table3">
                        <tr>
                            <td >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("Food_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                               <b> <%#Eval("Title")%></b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" class="ImgKidFood">
                                <asp:Image ID="Img"  Width="680px" Height="145px" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Pictures") %>' runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="direction:rtl; text-align:right;">



                                <asp:GridView ID="ShowFoodMenu2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                    BorderStyle="None" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="100%" 
                                     >
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                             <table align="center" class="TableListMenu">
                                            <tr>
                                            <td  class="Add">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" 
                                                    runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                                    CommandName="Select" Text="Select"  
                                                    onclick="LinkButton2_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>



                                                </td>

                                                <td class="ToCenter">
                                                       <b><%#Eval("Title_Pr") %>
                                                       </b>

                                                  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton12" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>"  CommandName="Link2" Text='<%# Eval("Menu_ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </td>

                                                 <td class="PriceLeft">
                                                       <%#Eval("Price") %>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <hr />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>

                                <br /><br /><br />





                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>


        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

As u can see the second gidview named id is ShowFoodMenu2 and it's inside  first girdview which id Giridview1 .

and also I have two Linkbuttons inside the second gridview 
one of them keep the value(which is LinkButton12) and another one(LinkButton2) is for when I clicked it add a record in Database .

But when I clicked on Linkbutton(LinkButton2) to show the value of Linkbutton12 , I will get ann error

Here is the error

http://hidelion.com/Images/error.png

and here is my.cs code

```
  protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridView G = new GridView();
        G.FindControl("ShowFoodMenu2");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        LinkButton m = (LinkButton)sender;
        int i = Int32.Parse(m.CommandArgument);
        LinkButton LblMososID = (LinkButton)G.Rows[i].FindControl("LinkButton2");
       // LinkButton LblMososID2 = (LinkButton)G.Rows[i].FindControl("LinkButton12");



        Label1.Text = LblMososID.Text;
    }
```

So how can I solved this problem ??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridView G = new GridView();` just create a new instance of Gridview class, and it will not find your gridview automatically, You are messing it up, simply go like this, from linkbutton find the corresponding row, from that row fetch the control you wish to manipulate, do it like this:-

```
protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton LinkButton2 = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)LinkButton2.NamingContainer;
        LinkButton LinkButton12 = (LinkButton)grdRow.FindControl("LinkButton12 ");
        Label1.Text = LinkButton12.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Thank u for answering, I used ur code but still I got an error but this time different error , would u please check the link blow to see what kind of error I got , [link](http://hidelion.com/Images/error3.png) , what should I do now ????

Comment: This is null reference error that means you are getting LinkButton12 as null..please debug nd check the reason.